# Devise ajax modal login not working with Rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, devise

I have come through several guides how to implement ajax authorization but non of them worked in my environment with Rails 5.0.0

So, I have:

### 1. Cloned the Devise Controllers

```
Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

    if resource.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
      sign_in :user, resource
      return render nothing: true
    end

    invalid_login_attempt
  end

  protected

  def invalid_login_attempt
    set_flash_message(:alert, :invalid)
    render json: flash[:alert], status: 401
  end
```

### 2. Set up the routes

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations'}, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login' }
```

### 3. Form

```
<%= form_for(resource, url: session_path(:user), :html => {:id => "login-box", :class => "contact-form"}, :remote => true ) do |f| %>
```

### 4. js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //form id
    $('#login-box').ajaxSuccess( function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
      console.log('success');
    });

    $('#login-box').ajaxFail(function(evt, xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
});
```

### 5. devise.rb config

```
  config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
  config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :json]
```

When I, trying to login I get this response for invalid data

```
    Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-20 18:29:55 +0300
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "button"=>""}
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

and this one for valid (**it does authorize, but ajax is not firing** and have to reload page manually to check if I'm logined or not)

```
Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-20 18:31:29 +0300
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"xs290@me.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "button"=>""}
  ......
   (3.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ....
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT

  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 176ms (Views: 3.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly the Stackoverflow markdown parser does not handle the combination of lists and code blocks very well at all. Maybe some day in the future we will get GFM code blocks but until then its better to use subheadings like `## 1. Did something`

Comment: IMHO you should actually trigger a page reload and not just handle it with ajax when the user signs in / out. Its simpler and there are far fewer edges cases and gotchas.

Comment: Max, thanks for help with formatting. Reloading page might be ok if login is success, but I can't see application with displaying error is modal (magnific popup)

Comment: Did you notice empty email in your ajax call?

Comment: Sergio, yes, it's ok because if I submit empty fields I need some feedback errors as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after reading more about the issue on the web I developed my solution based on [this article](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216837/) (not in English, but I believe it's fair to mention the source).

I guess my problem was mostly with firing ajax events.

**sessions/new view**

```
<%= form_for(User.new, url: session_path(:user), :html => {:id => "login-box", :class => "contact-form", :'data-type' => 'json'}, :remote => true ) do |f| %>
```

**Devise config** (back to defaults)

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true
```

**Sessions controller**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  respond_to :html, :json

end
```

**That's right, no extra code to controller.** And this works both for html and ajax requests. It can be useful if you have some with required current_user and you have redirect_to :login_path (for example creating new post)

Finally and most importantly this 
**jquery**
code works perfect for me

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '#login-box', function(e) {
    return $.magnificPopup.close();
    window.location.reload();
});

$(document).on('ajax:error', '#login-box', function(event, xhr, settings, exceptions) {
    var error_messages;

    error_messages = xhr.responseJSON['error'] ? "<div class='alert alert-danger pull-left'>" + xhr.responseJSON['error'] + "</div>" : xhr.responseJSON['errors'] ? $.map(xhr.responseJSON["errors"], function(v, k) {
         return "<div class='alert alert-danger pull-left'>" + k + " " + v + "</div>";
       }).join("") : "<div class='alert alert-danger pull-left'>Unknown error</div>";
       return $('#login-box').prepend(error_messages);
});
```

Comment: You do realize that the `window.location.reload();` line will never be reached since it is after the return?

Answer (score 1):

I was actually surprised at how easy it was once you drop all that Rails UJS "ajax for idiots" nonsense.

Setup a basic form. This is based on the `devise/sessions/new` view.

```
# remote: false  is not really needed.  
<%= form_for(User.new, as: :user, url: session_path(:user), html: { id: 'login-form'}, remote: false ) do |f| %>

  <div class="errors"></div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

And the just your run of the mill ajax handler:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#login-form', function(){
  var $form, $btn;

  $form = $(this);
  $btn = $form.find('input[type="submit"]');
  $form.find('.errors').remove();

  $.post({
    url: this.action,
    data: $form.serialize()
  }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    $form.prepend('<div class="errors">Invalid email or password</div>');
    // Unlocks the UI button
    $btn.prop( "disabled", false );
  });

  // prevent default submission
  return false;
});
```

If you are using turbolinks it will automatically pick up the ajax success event and clear the page cache and reload the page.

Otherwise just add a `.done` callback to the promise.

```
$.post({
  url: this.action,
  data: $form.serialize()
}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  $form.prepend('<div class="errors">Invalid email or password</div>');
  // Unlocks the UI button
  $btn.prop( "disabled", false );
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: It surprises me how many hoops people are willing to jump though instead of just writing 10 lines of javascript to get the job done.

Comment: I appreciate your help and you solution seems to be working. But I used to get no routes error on localhost/[Object] instead of '/users/login' . Finally I come up with an bit different solution (I'll update my answer soon with solution worked best for me)